# Identifying near-identical sections of text across documents in Python

Tags: python, nlp, duplicates

I need a method to clean up an arbitrary set of emails by identifying identical or near-identical footers that occur in many of them. These could be signatures, company boilerplate, etc. Before I write something up myself, I was wondering if there any off-the-shelf solution? Most of the deduplication libraries I've found are document-level.

Comment: You could copy the footers out into their own separate documents, then use the aforementioned deduplication libraries.

Comment: @john-gordon Sorry if it wasn't clear--I need to automatically identify the footers/repeated content

Comment: So do you actually care if the repeated content is in a footer, or can it be anywhere in the document?  If you do care that it is in a footer, how do you define "footer"?

Comment: @john-gordon For my present use case, these are most likely to be footers (i.e. they occur at the end of the email), but I don't care where in the document the repeated content occurs.

Comment: Based on your description of the problem, TheFuzz ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/thefuzz/), [GitHub](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) could help you with your project